# blank page even after changing permissions for symfony

Tags: symfony, deployment, project, file-permissions

I uploaded my Symfony Website to the host.

I am following docs as in the [website](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html).

All the actions are not working. I issued a `clear cache` and a `chmod -R 777`, but I just have blank pages for the working routes.

I don't understand.
I read on some website like 'we need to change file Permissions of cache & logs folder'.
I changed them using FTP but still I am getting same problem.
any idea about this?
please help me?

Comment: What about Apache and/or PHP logs ?

Comment: What do you mean by Apache and PHP logs? sorry i dnt know that

Comment: I mean looking for errors in logs from Apache and/or PHP. They might be located at `/var/logs/apache2`, `/var/logs/php5`, `/var/logs/httpd` but it depends on what operating system you are using/

Comment: I am using linux inside var i have log folder but there is no apache or php

Comment: What Linux distro ? php, logs and httpds are supposed to be inside the "logs" folder, not directly in the "var" one. Do you know what HTTP server you are using ? lighttpd ?

Comment: For example in Ubuntu the path for php log is `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and for mysql log is `/var/log/mysql/error.log`

Comment: Edit app.php: $kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);  Setting the second parameter to true should generate an error screen.

Comment: i did my project in windows,i moved it into centoS.is this reson for that?

Comment: in error log PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Templating\\TemplateReference in /var/www/html/drivekool_new/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/TemplateReference.php on line 22

Comment: after i re installed vendors this error came Class 'Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\SessionListener' not found in /var/www/html/drivekool_new/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/EventListener/SessionListener.php on line 23

Comment: Did you complete reinstall all Symfony2 ? Or did you copy/paste your project from Win to CentOS ?